# AS3 How to determine the sequence of events

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, events, list

I am using flex-4-tree (https://github.com/wasbridge/flex-4-tree)
in a mobile phone AIR app.

The Tree CLass:

```
public class Tree extends List
{
    ...
    dataSource.addEventListener(TreeEvent.NODE_EXPANDED, nodeExpandedHandler);
    dataSource.addEventListener(TreeEvent.NODE_COLLAPSED, nodeCollapsedHandler);
    ...
}
```

There is a menu on the main screen of the app.
If the user selects a menu-item, the appropriate action is taken,
but if the user expands/collapses a menu-item by selecting the expander icon, 
the menu-item is expanded/collapsed.

Currently the List change Event is received before the
flex-4-tree Expand/Collapse Events.

I need to receive the flex-4-tree Expand/Collapse Events before 
the List change Event.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Events happen when they happen, you cannot change their order. It'd be like saying I want my water to boil before I heat it up.

Comment: @Laurent If you have control over the source code you can easily change the order events are dispatched; although in this case it does not sound like such an undertaking would be trivial, since he is dealing w/ Flex Framework code.  I'd look at a different way to queue up your actions in the relevant event handlers.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com, his question indeed is how to change the event order of a third-party library and this cannot be done (just wouldn't make sense). He can indeed hack the source but he'll probably create many other problems along the way. Most likely he just need to set some boolean in the first event handler, then check this boolean in the second event handler and do something if it's on.

Comment: Either way, relying on Event execution order is _evil_ practice.

Comment: What is the end goal of this? Sometimes the first approach we think of (maybe naiive, more than evil) isn't the one that will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a timer in your handler for the ListChangeEvent that defers any action for a tenth of a second. Then if you expand/contract event comes in before the timer ends, you can cancel the action for the change event.  Something like this:

```
private var _expandEventOccurred:Boolean = false;

private function handleListChange(evt:Event):void {

    var timer:Timer = new Timer(100,1);  //100ms = 0.1s
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, handleListChangeTimerEvent);
    timer.start();

}

private function handleExpandContract(evt:Event):void {

    _expandEventOccured = true;

    //perform whatever other actions you need for the expand/contract event

}

private function handleListChangeTimerEvent(evt:Event):void {

    if(_expandEventOccured) {
        _expandEventOccured = false;
        return;
    }

    _expandEventOccured = false;  //needed here as well

    //perform whatever other actions you need for the list change event 

}
```

Not the cleanest thing in the world, but should do the trick.  Hope that helps!